# How do I prevent an enemy from spawning on the rocket Ship or at least away from the rocket Ship?

Tags: java

This is where the error is. It tells me that it was expecting != but it got =. When I tried to see what the outcome was by putting != it says that enemyX could not be found. I have commented out where the error is:

```
//methods to control the ship
move();
drawRocketShip();
for (int i = 0; i < enemies.size (); i++)
{
  enemies.get(i).drawEnemyShip();
}

if (millis() > startTime + 2500)
{
  score++;
  startTime = millis();
  Enemy e = new Enemy(gen.nextInt(1860) - 20, gen.nextInt(20) + 960);
  enemies.add(e);
  //if(enemyX = x && enemyY = y)
  //{
      //Enemy e = new Enemy(gen.NextInt(20) + 1860, gen.nextInt(20) + 960);
       //enemies.add(e);
  //}
//}
for (int i = 0; i < enemies.size (); i++)
{
  Enemy e = enemies.get(i);
  e.drawEnemyShip();
}
```

This is the enemy class:

```
    //draw enemy ship
    import java.util.Random;
    public class Enemy{
      public int enemyX = 0;
      public int enemyY = 0;
    public int dx = 0;
    public int dy = 0;
    Random gen = new Random();
      public Enemy(int a, int b){
        enemyX = a; 
        enemyY = b;
        dx = gen.nextInt(20) - 5;
        dy = gen.nextInt(20) - 5;
       }

      public void drawEnemyShip()
      {
      //enemy 1 body shape
      fill(128, 128, 0);
      ellipse(enemyX, enemyY, 40, 40);
      }
    }
```

I am trying to get the enemy ship to randomly spawn on the screen but also make sure that it doesn't spawn on top of the rocket ship. I tried something, but I keep getting this error.

Comment: "*I tried something, but I keep getting an error.*"  Unless you provide a good **detailed** description of your problem, this question will be shut down real fast.

Comment: Posting a whole bunch of source code and saying _"It's broken"_ does not help us answer your question.  Please rephrase your question with a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), with emphasis on Minimal, and point out the point in your code where the error occurs.  See: [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more guidelines on how to produce a question that helps us help you.

Comment: That's my mistake, hope I have been more specific with this edit.

Comment: Add the stack trace itself.

Comment: No need @Adam, the solution is pretty obvious once you look at his if statement.

Comment: @JasonThompson I see that now that you point that out. I wasn't paying close enough attention. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're referring to the 'if' statement that is currently commented out. If so, you have to use two = for boolean operations in java. So == instead of =.

One = is an assignment operator. Two = is a comparison operator.

More information about Java operators:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html